# Current and Voltage opposite polarity power supply

Tags: power-supply

Is there an instance where a power supply can generate a current that is the opposite polarity to the voltage, exactly 180 degrees out of phase?

If so is this power able to drive any electronic load?

Comment: What? Current is flowing from `-` to `+` in a power supply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, rotating machinery generators can do this. Normally the current and voltage are in phase, but they can also be in opposite phase.

When current and voltage are in opposite phase, it is called a motor.

Of course that means it consumes power from its electrical supply, so the only way it can drive an electronic load is by turning the shaft of another generator.

That is then called a [motor-generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor%E2%80%93generator).

Answer (score 1):

If it's doing this it's not producing power, it's consuming power.

For example, a battery that is being charged is doing this.